# how does the gem backbone-on-rails generate its templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, rubygems, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to understand how the gem [backbone-on-rails](https://github.com/meleyal/backbone-on-rails) works under the hood.

My problem right now is that I don't know who is in charge of generating the code for the templates it provides.

After installing and setting it up (I'm using the plain js route, not coffeescript, but the question is the same), if I write a template file in `/app/assets/templates/hello.jst`, it gets "somehow" translated to the following javascript inside `application.js`:

```
(function() {
 this.JST || (this.JST = {});
 this.JST["hello"] = function(obj){ <ugly js here> };
);
```

But who actually does generate that code? I've browsed the sourcecode of `backbone-on-rails`, and could not find anything that pointed to template compilation. Is the asset pipeline capable of doing that out of the box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I found my answer.

The functionality is provided by sprokets, [there is a good explanation on its readme](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#javascript-templating-with-ejs-and-eco).

Will close this in two days.